# vector spaces and euclidean n space

Tags: vector-spaces

What's the difference between a real vector space and a euclidean $n$-space ?Are there any ? Both are denoted by $\mathbb{R}^n$ but we need $10$ axioms to define a vector space, but not the $n$-space. So I'm quite confused.

Comment: It's not true that both are denoted by $\mathbb R^n$.  Only Euclidean $n$-space is denoted $\mathbb R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

$\Bbb R^n$  is just one example of a vector space.  Consider the trivial vector space {$0$}.  Or the vector space formed by the matrices  $F^{m x n} $.

Fields are a general example of a vector space.  So $\Bbb Q$ is a good example that this is more complicated than just $\Bbb R^n $.